# Did Walter Pitts refuse to allow his name to be made publicly available?

Tags: biographical-details, computer-science, neuroscience, cybernetics

I read on [the Wikipedia page on Walter Pitts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Pitts) that  :

> Pitts was also described as an eccentric, refusing to allow his name
>   to be made publicly available. He refused all offers of advanced
>   degrees or official positions at MIT as he would have to sign his
>   name.

It came to me as a surprise as he seems to have use his name in his [research articles](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Walter%20Pitts&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C22&as_sdtp=).

Did Walter Pitts refuse to allow his name to be made publicly available, or that some myth?

Comment: It's a fairly poorly written page; I wish there was better information there. Really good question.

Comment: Lettvin wrote about this in a reference I have been unable to find but read several years ago, Lettvin's own autobiography, so the claim has some truth to it, but the WHY, I don't since Lettvin didn't mention WHY.